# Node.js API is not returning anything (no errors)

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mean-stack

My API is not throwing any error ( as it is printing `Listening on Port 3000` on the console ) but it isn't returning anything either. When I try testing it on postman, it says `Could not get any response`.

Can anyone help me with figuring out what the problem could be? The code is below.

PS: I have been referring this [CRUD operations tutorial](https://appdividend.com/2018/11/04/angular-7-crud-example-mean-stack-tutorial/)

This is my file structure:

[image]

server.js

```
const express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const resortRoute = require('./routes/resort_routes');
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db', { useNewUrlParser: true })  //mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
    var db = mongoose.connection

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Mongodb connection error:'))

    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(cors());
    app.use('/resort', resortRoute);
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    const server = app.listen(function(){
        console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
    });
```

Resort model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var childSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    price : Number
}, { _id : false });

let Resort = new Schema({
  cover_image : {
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  price: {
      actual_price: { type: Number, required: true},
      discount_price: {type: Number, required: true}
  },
  themes : { type: Array },
  features : { type : Array },
  food : [childSchema],
  trip_type: { type : Array },
  stay_package : [childSchema],
  additional : [childSchema],
  activities : [childSchema],
  name : {
      type: String,
      required: true
  },

  excerpt : {
      type: String,
  },

  description : {
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  destinationId : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'Destination', required: true },
  itinerary : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed },
  maps : {
      type : String,
      // required: true
  },
  address : {
      type : String,
      // required: true
  },


  distance_from : {
      location : String,
      distance : Number,
  }
},{
    collection: 'resort'
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Resort', Resort);
```

resort_routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const resortRoutes = express.Router();


let Resort = require('../models/Resort');
resortRoutes.route('/create').post(function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
  let resort = new Resort(req.body);
  resort.save()
    .then(resort => {
      res.status(200).json({'resort': 'resort added'});
    })
    .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});

module.exports = resortRoutes;
```

Comment: What url are putting in postman ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi ````localhost:3000/resort/create````

Comment: I tried your code with a post request on `localhost:3000/resort/create` using Postman, everything works fine here. I would check the `port`, file paths

Comment: @MoadEnnagi hello, I've checked those, I have added file structure to the question, could you check once? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Image is too small

Comment: @MoadEnnagi Sorry about that, check now :)

Comment: Are you sure you set your method to POST at client and postman ?

Comment: @DarknessZX yes

Comment: Copy the post route (`localhost:3000/resort/create`) and paste in your browser, what de you get ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi it says ````This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.````

Comment: Did you get anything in your server when you got the message in your browser ? What server are your running ? (nodemon, node...) ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi no, when I first run the server, I get a message saying "liatening on port 3000" (as expected) but that's it, I don't get any other messages on the server.

Comment: I am running nodemon

Comment: However I tried ````node server.js````, and ````npm start```` too, it's not working.

Comment: Could you change your `port` to 4521 in `const port = 4521;` for example, and send a post request to `localhost:4521/resort/create`, what happens ?

Comment: I tried that, it gives me the same output :/